# Adding Android to Ionic 2 project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have seen similar questions but could not solve my problem.

I have an Ionic 3 project and want to add Android.

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

After a few minutes it will ask me:

```
Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it?
```

Which I answer with YES.

Then after a while it will tell me:

```
[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add
```

So it's kind of a chicken-egg problem.

Any ideas what to do?

Here is the full console output:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
> cordova platform add android --save
✔ Running command - done!
> ionic cordova resources android --force
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

? Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova platform add android --save
✔ Running command - done!
[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add
```

Comment: In your "package.json" file, do you have something like this?
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]

Comment: Can you share with us your root project content ( folders in root) ?